# USB Endoscope not recognised as a MTP Device. How to Correct?

Tags: 14.04, usb, mtp, evdev

I have a newly acquired USB Endoscope (aka 'snake camera') which works a treat on a friend's Apple Mac, but does not work on my Dell laptop running 14.04.

The Endoscope is recognised as a device:

```
$ ls -l /dev/video*
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 Sep 18 21:05 /dev/video0
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 1 Sep 18 22:11 /dev/video1
```

(The first device is the laptop's built-in webcam)

Neither Cheese nor the GTK UVC viewers can 'see' the Endoscope, and the issue would seem to be that it is not seen as a MTP device:-

```
mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 8 was not an MTP device
```

Having looked at various forums and reports, it would seem that the MTP software needs to know the device ID. Is that correct?  How can this be arranged?

Lastly, is it possible to use something other than MTP, which seems to be biased towards music devices?

As requested:-

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:64ad Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 090c:f37d Silicon Motion, Inc. - Taiwan (formerly Feiya Technology Corp.) 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c016 Logitech, Inc. Optical Wheel Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:07e6 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I have installed the mtp-tools suite, and get the following from mtp-detect:-

```
~$ mtp-detect
Unable to open ~/.mtpz-data for reading, MTPZ disabled.libmtp version: 1.1.6

Listing raw device(s)
   No raw devices found.
```

Additionally, I have spotted the following in the Xorg log which may be relevant?:-

```
[   444.521] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HD Endoscope Camera (/dev/input/event11)
[   444.521] (**) HD Endoscope Camera: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[   444.522] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'HD Endoscope Camera'
[   444.522] (**) HD Endoscope Camera: always reports core events
[   444.522] (**) evdev: HD Endoscope Camera: Device: "/dev/input/event11"
[   444.522] (--) evdev: HD Endoscope Camera: Vendor 0x90c Product 0xf37d
[   444.522] (--) evdev: HD Endoscope Camera: Found keys
[   444.522] (II) evdev: HD Endoscope Camera: Configuring as keyboard
[   444.522] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/input/input12/event11"
[   444.522] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "HD Endoscope Camera" (type: KEYBOARD, id 14)
[   444.522] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[   444.522] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   444.522] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "gb"
[   444.537] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-B8CD4FE5A1833D7AB4B402792017A55B628FCF2D.xkm
```

Surely Ubuntu should not be treating the Endoscope as a keyboard ???  Or is this some sort of default as it is not being recognised as a mtp device ?

Output from jmtpfs:-

```
$ jmtpfs -l
Unable to open ~/.mtpz-data for reading, MTPZ disabled.Available devices  (busLocation, devNum, productId, vendorId, product, vendor):
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add `lsusb` output.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** Could you please review my [edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/675742/revisions) and also review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your questions in the future... **;-)**

Comment: Thank you for your edits Fabby. Will look at the formatting options.

Comment: Have added a bit more info.. Can anyone comment on the Xorg string please?  If there are multiple issues with using this device on Ubuntu, I do not have the knowledge to pursue them!

Comment: The clue is in the error message: `[   444.521] (**) HD Endoscope Camera: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"` The meaning of "catchall" in this case is the kernel saying "I have found no match for this device, try the catchall, maybe that will work". It didn't.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer, but may help you along the path. Read these `man` pages:

```
jmtpfs (1)           - FUSE based filesystem for accessing MTP devices
             from package jmtpfs
mtp-server (1)       - A simple MTP server implementation
                 from package mtp-server
mtp_basic (3)        - The basic device management API.
mtp_internals (3)    - The libmtp internals API.
                 from package libmtp-doc
qlix (1)             - Manage MTP devices
             from package qlix
```

Comment: Hello waltinator. I have installed jmtpfs but this can not see the Endoscope either:-

Comment: If it does not show with `lsusb`, or `jmtpfs --listDevices` it is not connected. What does `dmesg -T` show just after you plug it in?

Comment: Hello waltinator. Thanks for the response, but this question may be closed off as I have found the Endoscope works fine on another Dell laptop which is also running 14.04 !  (I shall try to run a comparison to find out why it still won't work on my Dell ...)